# Microsoft Azure speech to text doesn't recognize .wav audio when generated by PC microphone

Tags: node.js, azure, audio, speech-to-text

I am trying to use Azure speech to text as part of a larger app. When I input a .wav audio file generated by Azure text to speech, or I input a .wav file downloaded from the internet, my Azure speech to text script works. However, when I use a .wav file recorded from my PC microphone the script never returns. The files are all in the same folder and I never get an invalid path error, except when I deliberately use a nonexistent file.

When I call `transcribe_speech("./uploads/downloaded_from_azure_synthesis.wav")` I get the correct output printed to the terminal.
However when I call `transcribe_speech("./uploads/recorded_from_pc.wav")` I get no output. Furthermore the last statement printed is "in promise". "In speech recognizer" is never printed, indicating the script never gets past `speechRecognizer.recognized...` and stalls forever.

My PC is a Lenovo Yoga running Windows 11

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

async function transcribe_speech(input_file) {
  const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(process.env.SPEECH_KEY, process.env.SPEECH_REGION);
  speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "he-IL";
  const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync(input_file));
  const speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let response = "";
    console.log("In promise")
    speechRecognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
      console.log("In speech recognizer")
      if (e.result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        response += e.result.text;
        console.log("In recognized speech")
      } else if (e.result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.log("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
      }
    };

    speechRecognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
      console.log("Session stopped.");
      speechRecognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      resolve(response);
    };

    speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
  });
}

module.exports = { transcribe_speech }

transcribe_speech("./uploads/recorded_from_pc.wav")
.then((msg) => {
    console.log("Recognition completed. Final response:");
    console.log(msg);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Recognition error:");
    console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes to your code and got the text output with input speech generated by my PC microphone.***

**Code:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");

async function transcribe_speech(input_file, key, region) {
  const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key, region);
  speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "he-IL";
  const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync(input_file));
  const speechRecognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let response = "";
    console.log("In promise");

    speechRecognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
      console.log("In speech recognizer");
      if (e.result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        response += e.result.text;
        console.log("In recognized speech");
      } else if (e.result.reason === sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.log("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
      }
    };

    speechRecognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
      console.log("Session stopped.");
      speechRecognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      resolve(response);
    };

    speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
  });
}

module.exports = { transcribe_speech };

const speechKey = "<speech-key>";
const speechRegion = "<speech-region>";

transcribe_speech("<path/to/uploads/recorded_from_pc.wav>", speechKey, speechRegion)
  .then((msg) => {
    console.log("Recognition completed. Final response:");
    console.log(msg);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Recognition error:");
    console.error(err);
  });
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "speech-to-text-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Speech to Text Example",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.20.0",
    "wav": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and gives the text output with input speech generated by my PC microphone as below,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I don't see how your code is substantively different from mine.  The fact that the code works for you but doesn't for me just highlights there must be some issue with how Azure handles certain mic inputs. May I ask what PC and OS you are running the script from?

Comment: @MartinChapman I am running the script in Windows 11, OS - 22621.1992.

Comment: @MartinChapman Do you set up your microphone setting on your PC?
If not, you can go to **Settings** > **Privacy** > **Microphone** to check and adjust the microphone permissions. Then record a few audio lines and convert that audio to a **.wav** file. Try to rerun the script.

Comment: I have no problems listening to the .wav recordings created by my microphone.

Comment: I found some discussion on github saying that Azure stt won't accept microphone audio. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @MartinChapman Yes, that's correct. The Microsoft Azure Speech to Text (STT) service does not directly accept audio from a microphone as input. The Azure STT service is primarily designed to transcribe pre-recorded audio files, such as WAV or MP3 files.
I also provided speech as an audio file then it converts to text only.

Comment: I am recording microphone audio then saving it as a .wav and it is not working. Are you sure that Azure stt can accept mp3? The documentation says that it cannot accept mp3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254523/discussion-between-dasari-kamali-and-martin-chapman).